# Excel clears clipboard on protecting/unprotecting sheet by VBA but retains it when done by using UI i.e Review -> Protect / Unprotect?

Tags: vba, excel

I have come across a strange problem in Microsoft Excel for Mac 16.11. It is equally true for Windows version too. If I copy some cell(s) and use VBA to protect or unprotect the sheet, the clipboard clears. Here is the code that I use for protect - unprotect :

Sheet1.Unprotect("abc")
Sheet1.Protect("abc")

But if I copy some cell(s) and use the UI i.e Review -> Protect, Unprotect, the clipboard is retained and I can even see that the dotted green coloured border across the copied cells is intact, unlike the former case.

I can use MSForms.DataObject to manually save the clipboard text(it works) before calling protect / unprotect and restore it after the call but then the dotted green coloured border goes away which can cause confusion to user.

Is there a way to imitate in VBA what the UI does when protecting /unprotecting ?

Comment: Use [worksheet.protect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel) with the UserInterfaceOnly=true once and you will never have to unprotect it again to perform vba actions.

Comment: I had tried it many times. Sadly there are two major problems. I am using DrawingObjects:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True. First something like TargetRange.ClearFormats on a protected sheet causes excel to crash. Secondly code to add drop down menu to cell doesn't work on a protected cell.

Comment: Can you just copy the selection again after protecting (`Sheet1.Protect: Selection.Copy`) or unprotecting: `Sheet1.Unprotect: Selection.Copy`?

Answer (score 3):

I came across something while researching something else, I think it might be an answer to this, see http://www.excel-first.com/autoexpand-excel-tables-on-protected-sheets/

In short, it seems it's a common problem when running macros/code and that you can prevent Excel from clearing the clipboard by opening it first (you then have to close it after) using:

```
OpenClipboard 0

~the action that would make Excel clear the clipboard~

CloseClipboard
```

Comment: You also need to declare the following:
`Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long`

`Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long`

and if you're running a 64 bit version of excel you need to modify it like this:
`Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long`

`Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long`